# How can I make a password to open up a page using a button an edit Text box and if/else statement (Android)

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, if-statement

I am trying to make a password to get into an a page in Android. I am using a String password to store a password. ie String password = bob. I am using an EditText box to enter a word and currently I am using an if else statement to check if the password and the EditText input are correct. To  carry out this function I am using a button to make this check.

Here is the code I have made so far

```
package com.example.explicitintent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Button invokingButtons = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    invokingButtons.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String password = "bob";
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    if(myEditText.equals(password)){
    Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(explicitIntent);

}else{

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show  ();

                }
        }
        });


            };
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get any text with the help of getText() method of EditText class.
eg:

EditText edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your-edittext-id);

String pass = edit.getText().toString();

Comment: Thanks for the help Satya. I'm a bit new to programming so I didn't get it but thanks for the help. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if(myEditText.equals(password))
```

with

```
if(myEditText.getText().toString().equals(password))
```

Comment: @RobCarrigan: if u find any answer useful just accept it...it will motivate the users to answer and will be more useful for people wid same issues